# XCode 6 - Auto Layout

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode6

I am just starting a new app and the request came to use Interface Builder this time (I normally do all my stuff programmatically) but anyway.

I am trying to have 2 Image Views sit next to each other on both Portrait and Landscape.

I was toying with the storyboard file and I came close but somehow I can't nail it down to work on Landscape.

It seems that my views are always bigger then the actual screen size and on landscape my views overlap each other.

Am I missing something with the auto-layout process?

Thank you in advance.

So here is a visual representation of what I am trying to do:

[image: portrait]
[image: landscape]

Comment: "Am I missing something with the auto-layout process?" Most likely, but how are we supposed to know if you don't tell us how you set up your constraints?

Comment: Oops sorry 'bout that. My problem is solved though but for general purpose.

I started out by adding horizontal spaces to 1 view. then duplicate that view and give the both a equal height.
After that I added some vertical space because of the change in height when rotating. After that it was all just a general mess...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done a very similar task recently, here is my way:

**1-** Select your view controller in UI Builder

**2-** `Editor->Resolve Auto Layout Issues->Clear All Constraints` in View Controller

Now, we don't have any constraints on our View Controller.

**3-** Select both of the views(You can do it easier on Document Outline View)

**4-** `Editor->Pin->Widths Equally`

**5-** Repeat Step 3

**6-** `Editor->Pin->Heights Equally`

Xcode will complain about missing constraints at this point.

**7-** Repeat Step 1

**8-** `Editor->Resolve Auto Layout Issues->Add Missing Constraints` in View Controller

This should now work on all layout directions.